# using parallel partition-er in c#

Tags: c#

can u tell how to find smallest in this array using parallel partition er

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly int[] Data = new[] { 3, 4, 34, 22, 34, 3, 4, 4, 2, 7, 3, 8, 122, -1, -3, 1, 2 };

    private static int FindSmallest(IList<int> numbers)
    {
        if (numbers.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("There must be at least one element in the array");
        }
        int smallestSoFar = numbers[0];
        foreach (int number in numbers)
        {
            if (number < smallestSoFar)
            {
                smallestSoFar = number;
            }
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Join("; ", numbers) + ": " + smallestSoFar);
        return smallestSoFar;
    }


    private static void ParallelPartitionGenerateAESKeys()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var pratition = Partitioner.Create(0, Data.Length, 
            ((int) (Data.Length/Environment.ProcessorCount) + 1));
        Parallel.ForEach
```

Comment: Creating a partitioner to do this in parallel will take more time than doing it in one thread.

Comment: For such a small array, yes I agree. For a large array, partitioner will be faster. No idea what the minimum size of array would be to make it faster, tho...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void Main()
{
    var result = Data.AsParallel().Min();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it, but this will be slower than a single thread for the small array you are using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    sealed class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            int[] data = { 3, 4, 34, 22, 34, 3, 4, 4, 2, 7, 3, 8, 122, -1, -3, 1, 2 };

            int smallest = int.MaxValue;
            object locker = new object();

            Parallel.ForEach
            (
                Partitioner.Create(0, data.Length),

                () => int.MaxValue,

                (subRange, loopState, threadLocalState, localData) =>
                {
                    for (int i = subRange.Item1; i < subRange.Item2; i++)
                        localData = Math.Min(localData, data[i]);

                    return localData;
                },

                finalThreadLocalState =>
                {
                    lock (locker)
                    {
                        smallest = Math.Min(smallest, finalThreadLocalState);
                    }
                }
            );

            Console.WriteLine("Smallest = " + smallest);
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

This should be faster than a single thread for large arrays, but exactly how large the array would need to be before it is faster will vary from computer to computer. The only way to know is to time it.

In fact, my preliminary tests seem to indicate that you need an array of at least half a million elements before the parallel version is significantly faster...